# Handle multiple domain names in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have two domain names

```
www.example1.com
www.example2.com
```

When these come into tomcat I want to direct them to the correct directory in order to get the resources.

I have 2 folders in my webapp folder within tomcat

```
/example1
/example2
```

For example: If I go onto `www.example.com` it should get the resources from the `example1` folder the webapps directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of pasting URLs as an answer, but this explains exactly what you're asking for: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/CreateVirtualHosts